# Problems with wrapping a C++ DLL from C#

Tags: c#, c++, dll, interop, word-wrap

I'm using System.Runtime.InteropServices to call several functions written in C++ from my C# app. I'm just having problems with a particular function that returns an array.

I've seen that my function shouldn't return anything, and a pointer to the "returning variable" should be en entry. But I'm not managing to do it properly.

For instance if I have a function in c++

```
void func(double *y, double *x){...}
```

that manipulates an array x and returns an array y.

I'm doing:

-in my .h:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void func(double *y,double *x);
```

-in my .cpp:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void func(double *y,double *x){...}
```

-in my c# code:

```
static class AnyClass
  {
    [DllImport(dllPath)]
    public extern static void func(out double[] y, double[] x);

    int otherfunc
    {
      double[] x = new double[5];
      double[] y = new double[5];

      ...

      func(out y, x); 
    }
  }
```

but it gives me a System.EntryPointNotFoundException.

Any clue?

Comment: Are you sure the names `func` and `function` are correct? Because they don't look as equal as they have to...

Comment: Your first code snippet has "x" as the 2nd parameter, your later ones have it in the reverse order.  You should make it consistent for clarity.

Comment: And does your function only work with arrays of size 5? Or do you need a size parameter?

Comment: The *out* keyword is quite wrong too.

Comment: To expand on Hans' comment, `out double[]` is equivalent to `double**`; you will certainly get incorrect behavior with that PInvoke signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EntryPointNotFoundException means that nothing called 'function' was found in your DLL.

In your .h file you call it 'func'. But in your .cpp file you call it 'function'. And since your .h file is the only place which is declaring `extern "C"`, what is effectively happening is that the function is being exported by your DLL c++-style-name-mangled, instead of plain-c-style. So, when C# looks for plain-c-style 'function', it cannot find it.

Comment: Then make sure the function in the .cpp file is also extern "C".

Comment: Okay, I looked at a project of mine, which _works_, and here is how I declare methods: (no need for a header file, only .cpp) `extern "C" { __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall Function( ... ) { } }`

Comment: I'm catching no exceptions now. But it still don't make changes on my array y. I've tryied also to print something inside the function and it's not being displayed.

Comment: Well, technically, this question has been answered, because your error is gone. Now you have another error.  I would recommend that you accept my answer, close this question, see if some of the other people's advice is helpful, (I think it is,) and if not, open a new question with the new situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you also have to specify `extern "C"` in your .cpp file. If not, you might end up with two different functions `func`, the one with the correct linkage only be declared and not defined.

Note: *Afair* the `extern "C"` linkage also specify how the functions are named in the DLL file. For C++ functions some pre- resp. postfixes are added to the name relating to the signature (i.e. the parameters and the return type). This is necessary because you can overload functions in C++. Therefore, if you don't specify `extern "C"`, the functions are named differently in the DLL and thus cannot be found by the managed code.

Answer (score 1):

An `EntryPointNotFoundException` means that the runtime failed to find the specified function name in your DLL.

Possible reasons are

- You misspelled the function name in your DLL or your program
- The you did not deactivate name mangling (`extern "C"`)

The first reason is easy to find, just double-check all names and make sure they are really equal. If for some reason you can not change the DLL, but like a different name from C#, you can use the [DllImportAttribute.EntryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.entrypoint.aspx) property to point to a function of a different name.

The second one is more difficult to come by. To diagnose the problem, I suggest you use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what really is going on inside your compiled DLL. Using that tool, you can see the function names, and whether they are C++'ified or not.

You already tried to use `extern "C"` to make sure the function name is not afflicted by name mangling. Maybe you did not include the .h file from your .cpp file, so that the compiler did not see the `extern "C"` at all.